# Bannered answer clean up (2011-2012)

Tags: support, answers, deletion

I've deleted the following old answers as unreferenced as abandoned. I've only removed answers which had absolutely no references, or completely inadequate references (e.g. "the sun is yellow [ref: wikipedia page on the color yellow]").

All of them had been previously bannered and have not improved in a long time.

Please review for any mistakes (or if you like, add references and signal for reopening!). Use one answer per... answer.

- [Answer 934](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/934/96) by horatio score 5 on "Can carbon in hair be proven to originate from corn?"
- [Answer 2133](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/2133/96) by M. Werner score 6 on "Would a large quantity of gasoline in a closed container explode violently when exposed to fire?"
- [Answer 2145](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/2145/96) by DVK score 19 on "Are humans the only species to have homophobes?"
- [Answer 2151](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/2151/96) by rooh score -1 on "Are humans the only species to have homophobes?"
- [Answer 2189](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/2189/96) by tak score 2 on "Risks of using a cast iron skillet on a flat/glass top electric range?"
- [Answer 2780](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/2780/96) by Rory Alsop score 6 on "\"We have the right tires for your driving style.\""
- [Answer 3017](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/3017/96) by sal score 3 on "Does consuming different types of alcohol make you more sick than others?"
- [Answer 424](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/424/96) by Christian score 3 on "Is alcohol a good enough pain killer to allow for surgery without the patient noticing?"
- [Answer 290](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/290/96) by David Hedlund score 8 on "Is alcohol a good enough pain killer to allow for surgery without the patient noticing?"
- [Answer 6542](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/6542/96) by MSalters score 21 on "Is chlorine in water absorbed quickly through the skin?"
- [Answer 1181](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/1181/96) by SophieMonster score 10 on "Are we eating too many carbs? And do we need to switch to the primal/paleo diet?"
- [Answer 4517](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/4517/96) by ratchet freak score 30 on "Can every grain of sand be addressed in IPv6?"
- [Answer 4515](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/4515/96) by blah score 55 on "Can every grain of sand be addressed in IPv6?"
- [Answer 6005](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/6005/96) by fredley score 44 on "Can you detect a hidden camera in a trial room/changing room with your phone?"
- [Answer 4220](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/4220/96) by Carl Zulauf score 24 on "Is fasting healthy?"
- [Answer 2586](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/2586/96) by DVK score 2 on "Do upper-income people in the US think they aren't upper income?"
- [Answer 2341](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/2341/96) by M. Werner score 26 on "How do Shaolin monks break spears with their neck?"

Comment: I'm a bit unhappy with grain of sand/IPv6 treatment, on philosophical grounds. You deleted answers that provide original research (which is fine)... but left an answer that basiclally links to a blog doing original research as a source - which IMHO is 100% as useful/useless as original research in the answer deleted. The fact that there is 1 more level of indirection doesn't add to authoritativeness; and linked blogs aren't AFAIK peer reviewed

Comment: @DVK I agree that's very borderline, happy to let other mods review it or community discuss it.

Answer (score -2):

I've left [this answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/4509/96) standing and DVK noted that its reference might not be authoritative enough.

> I'm a bit unhappy with grain of sand/IPv6 treatment, on philosophical grounds. You deleted answers that provide original research (which is fine)... but left an answer that basiclally links to a blog doing original research as a source - which IMHO is 100% as useful/useless as original research in the answer deleted. The fact that there is 1 more level of indirection doesn't add to authoritativeness; and linked blogs aren't AFAIK peer reviewed

-- [DVK](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3313/bannered-answer-clean-up-2011-2012?noredirect=1#comment10561_3313)

This is the reference: http://www.hawaii.edu/suremath/jsand.html

Should we mark the answer as unreferenced/theoretical?

Vote *up* to banner and eventually remove the answer
Vote *down* to keep the answer

Comment: This seems to be a theoretical answer which only uses trivial multiplication to prove its point, and which should be kept since the referenced numbers are both obtained from reputable sources.